# Can TSS (Threshold Signature Scheme) hold bitcoin account on Tezos directly?

Tags: wallets

TSS has been brought to Tezos 3 years ago by ZenGo (https://zengo.com/adding-threshold-signature-scheme-tss-to-tezos/).  This is a great feature but wasn't used widely by Tezos community.

Recently, Dfinity community proposed Threshold ECDSA Signatures ( https://forum.dfinity.org/t/threshold-ecdsa-signatures/6152 ) which can control a bitcoin address on Dfinity blockchain directly, this removes the necessarily of token wrapping.

So, is it possible to create a similar way of Threshold ECDSA Signatures on Tezos, which a real bitcoin address can be created by multiple parties (bakers ?) and remove the traditional ways of bridging or wrapping like tzBTC, ETHtz, USDtz, wWBTC, etc ?